# How to generate syntax-highlighted HTML from source code?

Tags: command-line, html, syntax-highlighting

Is there a command-line tool, preferably available on both Windows and Linux, which will take a source code file as input, and generate the corresponding syntax-coloured HTML code ?

I'm looking for functionality similar to vim's `TOhtml` command, but which I could run from the command line, without having to open vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.html) is pretty much exactly what you're looking for:

> Highlight converts sourcecode to HTML, XHTML, RTF, LaTeX, TeX, SVG, BBCode and terminal escape sequences with coloured syntax highlighting. Language definitions and colour themes are customizable.

The website has downloads for Windows (cli & gui) and packages for various Linux/BSD distros.

Comment: yep, perfect match; thanx !